# Remove duplicates and some rows depends conditions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I must remove duplicates mess from this table and remove some "wrong" mess present before a specific mess like 'okdepart'.
for exemple if mess depart are present before okdepart mess I need to remove it.
see for rnk_idid = 3 two mess depart which must removed
the original table

| rnk_idid | mess | date | code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | inbox | 19/12/2022 10:26 | 8813015 |
| 1 | arrived | 19/12/2022 10:27 | 8813015 |
| 1 | arrived | 19/12/2022 10:28 | 8813015 |
| 1 | ready | 19/12/2022 10:33 | 8813015 |
| 1 | i_watch | 19/12/2022 10:34 | 8813015 |
| 1 | okdepart | 19/12/2022 10:35 | 8813015 |
| 1 | o_watch | 19/12/2022 10:36 | 8813015 |
| 1 | sound | 19/12/2022 10:37 | 8813015 |
| 1 | outbox | 19/12/2022 10:38 | 8813015 |
| 1 | depart | 19/12/2022 10:39 | 8813015 |
| 1 | depart | 19/12/2022 10:40 | 8813015 |
| 3 | inbox | 19/12/2022 13:26 | 8813003 |
| 3 | arrived | 19/12/2022 13:27 | 8813003 |
| 3 | arrived | 19/12/2022 13:28 | 8813003 |
| 3 | depart | 19/12/2022 13:29 | 8813003 |
| 3 | depart | 19/12/2022 13:30 | 8813003 |
| 3 | arrived | 19/12/2022 13:31 | 8813003 |
| 3 | arrived | 19/12/2022 13:32 | 8813003 |
| 3 | ready | 19/12/2022 13:33 | 8813003 |
| 3 | i_watch | 19/12/2022 13:34 | 8813003 |
| 3 | okdepart | 19/12/2022 13:35 | 8813003 |
| 3 | o_watch | 19/12/2022 13:36 | 8813003 |
| 3 | sound | 19/12/2022 13:37 | 8813003 |
| 3 | outbox | 19/12/2022 13:38 | 8813003 |
| 3 | depart | 19/12/2022 13:39 | 8813003 |
| 3 | depart | 19/12/2022 13:40 | 8813003 |

expected table

| rnk_idid | mess | date | code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | inbox | 19/12/2022 10:26 | 8813015 |
| 1 | arrived | 19/12/2022 10:27 | 8813015 |
| 1 | ready | 19/12/2022 10:33 | 8813015 |
| 1 | i_watch | 19/12/2022 10:34 | 8813015 |
| 1 | okdepart | 19/12/2022 10:35 | 8813015 |
| 1 | o_watch | 19/12/2022 10:36 | 8813015 |
| 1 | sound | 19/12/2022 10:37 | 8813015 |
| 1 | outbox | 19/12/2022 10:38 | 8813015 |
| 1 | depart | 19/12/2022 10:39 | 8813015 |
| 3 | inbox | 19/12/2022 13:26 | 8813003 |
| 3 | arrived | 19/12/2022 13:27 | 8813003 |
| 3 | ready | 19/12/2022 13:33 | 8813003 |
| 3 | i_watch | 19/12/2022 13:34 | 8813003 |
| 3 | okdepart | 19/12/2022 13:35 | 8813003 |
| 3 | o_watch | 19/12/2022 13:36 | 8813003 |
| 3 | sound | 19/12/2022 13:37 | 8813003 |
| 3 | outbox | 19/12/2022 13:38 | 8813003 |
| 3 | depart | 19/12/2022 13:39 | 8813003 |

i tried first to create a rn with

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT c.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.rnk_idid, mess ORDER BY c.date) as RN
   FROM mytable c
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

The mess depart with rnk_idid = 3 before for okdepart is still present.

```
https://dbfiddle.uk/N9qg6hU_
```

Comment: Check your Fiddle - "not found"

Comment: under score at the end to url

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking - your result in the fiddle has 1 row for rnk_idid = 3 with *depart* and the correct earliest date - why would you have the row where it's "13:39" when you are ordering by date and there are 2 rows with an earlier date?

Comment: I would like to delete each depart message prior to the okdepart message but keep the one that would be present after this message. in the original table for group rnk_idid 3 I have two mess messages depart (13:29 and 13:30) before the mess okdepart (13:35) I must be able to eliminate them both. Whereas the last departure message (13:40) after okdepart must remain.

Comment: But in your desired results you have 13:39 not 13:40 so that does not make sense

Comment: if in the same group (here rnk_idid =3) the departure messages arrive after "okdepart" (time 13:35) then these are good messages (eg 13:39/13:40) otherwise they must all be deleted (messages departure (13:29/13:30) because before okdeparture In addition, all duplicate messages must be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query returns the exact expected table unless I missed something. You have 18 rows in the result and 18 rows in the expected table as well.

(1) If you want to remove in the result set of the query all the duplicated rows, when the entire row (all columns) is duplicate and not only specific column, then you can use DISTINCT instead of ROW_NUmber.

I will assume that you mean to check only duplicates values of `"mess"` column (even if the rest of columns are not the same)

(2) When you speak about `"if mess depart are present before okdepart mess"`, it is not clear to me if you mean all the rows before or just one row before.

I will assume that that you mean all rows before.

(3) It seems in first glance that your system design is not well since you should have prevent such data from getting into the database if it's wrong. You should understand why a person got twice "arrived" for example when a person can only arrive once. This should be your real concern.

#### Solution 1

According to your description assuming I understood it well and using the assumption above, this should solve your request (notice that we get 17 rows and not 18 like in your expected table since we remove the one before the mess = 'okdepart' and has mess = 'depart')

```
; WITH MyCTE as (
    select rnk_idid,mess,[date],code, 
        --Wrong = CASE WHEN mess = 'okdepart' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 
        SW = SUM(CASE WHEN mess = 'okdepart' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) over(PARTITION BY rnk_idid order by [date] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ),
        RN  =ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY rnk_idid, mess order by [date])
    from mytable t
    -- ORDER BY rnk_idid,[date]
)
SELECT rnk_idid,mess,[date],code--, Wrong, SW, RN
FROM MyCTE
WHERE RN = 1 and not (SW = 0 and mess = 'depart')
ORDER BY [date]
GO
```

#### (Update) Solution 2 - adding the new information from the comments

New info: You want the first row with mess='depart' which come after the row with mess = 'okdepart'.

```
; WITH MyCTE as (
    select rnk_idid,mess,[date],code, 
        SW = SUM(CASE WHEN mess = 'okdepart' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) over(PARTITION BY rnk_idid order by [date] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW )
    from mytable t
),
MyCTE02 as (
    select rnk_idid,mess,[date],code,
    RN  =ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY rnk_idid, mess order by [date])
    FROM MyCTE
    where NOT (SW = 0 and mess = 'depart')
)
SELECT rnk_idid,mess,[date],code,RN
FROM MyCTE02
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY [date]
GO
```

Comment: To understand the above solution better, you can unmark the commented columns and check what Wrong, SW, RN columns return. These are just helper for the sake of the forum.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have 26 lines at the start, 18 at the finish. point (2) correct. point (3) correct but I have no control over it. Your solution is almost complete because the last departure messages from group 3 have also left. These departure messages must remain because they come after okdepart. For the rnk_idid = 1 is ok. https://dbfiddle.uk/eXaogWQ-

Comment: OK, so this is a new information which was not in the question. You want the first row with `mess='depart'` which come after the row with `mess = 'okdepart'`. This is simple to change. We simply need first to remove the SW and only in the next step calculate the ROW_NUMBER from the rows that stays. I will add this option

Comment: Top! It does the job. Thanks a lot Ronen.

Comment: You are most welcome @leerickx `:-)` Happy to help when I can